# Why is the following Fourier-operation, involving $\mathcal{F(\delta)}$ and $\mathcal{F(\frac{dq}{dt})}$ legitimate?

Tags: fourier-analysis

[image]

How can we deduct $iwQ(w)+Q(w)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ ?

Answer (score 3):

From the first equation you have

$$\mathcal{F}\{q(t)\}+\mathcal{F}\left\{\frac{dq(t)}{dt}\right\}=\mathcal{F}\{\delta(t)\}\tag{1}$$

With $\mathcal{F}\{q(t)\}=Q(\omega)$ and with the differentiation property of the Fourier transform you get

$$\mathcal{F}\left\{{\frac{dq(t)}{dt}}\right\}=i\omega Q(\omega)$$

Finally, with $\mathcal{F}\{\delta(t)\}=1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ (1) can be rewritten as

$$Q(\omega)+i\omega Q(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$

Comment: But it seems like $\mathcal{F}\frac{dq(t)}{dt}=-iwQ(w)$ and why is  ${\mathcal{F}{\delta(t)}}=\frac{1}{2\pi}$

Comment: $\mathcal{F}\{\delta(t)\}=1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ because they appear to use the unitary version of the Fourier transform with angular frequency. Check [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Distributions). And as for the sign of $i\omega Q(\omega)$ you're wrong, please check [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Functional_relationships).